# Rails "POST" member route responds to all request types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes

I'm trying to set up a member route for my 'foo' controller, which is named 'bar' such that it should ONLY respond to post requests. However, I notice that in my RSpec tests it responds to ALL request types (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).

I was under the impression that defining the route as so, would restrict it such that it would only respond to POST requests:

```
resources :foo do
  member do
    post 'bar'
  do
end
```

This seems further confirmed by the fact that when I run `rake routes` it ONLY shows the 'bar' route like so:

```
bar_foo    POST    /foo/:id/bar(.:format)    {:action=>"bar", :controller=>"foo"}
```

However, from RSPEC, the following test fails (meaning the controller processes request successfully) for GET, PUT, & DELETE:

```
describe FooController do
    describe "GET bar" do
        it "should not be successful" do
            foo = FactoryGirl.create(:foo)
            get :bar, :id => foo.id
            response.should_not be_ok
        end
    end 
end
```

Am I missing something small here? How do I restrict my 'bar' member route to only respond to "post" requests.

EDIT:

This appears to be an issue with either RSpec 2.0 or [ActionController::TestCase](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html), because I get the following error when I try to hit **/foo/:id/bar** on my sever with anything but POST:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/foo/1/bar"
```

Comment: "puts response.inspect" and check the output.

Comment: the response is a 200, which is what the 'bar' action returns on success from the FooController

Comment: just to validate your sanity, I've written similar tests relying on routes to reject non-POST etc, and have had it work. It's the right strategy, must be some "mundane detail"

Comment: Thanks, it's always good to know you're not crazy :)

Comment: Does your test log indicate what path is actually being accessed on the `get :bar` call?  Does it list `Started GET "/foo/:id/bar" or something different?  Also, do you have a "catch-all" route at the bottom of your routes.rb?

Comment: Nope, don't have a catch-all route, and I didn't see anything like "Started ...." in the test log. I have a feeling that the request methods for testing don't interface the same way as a regular request from a browser, I think this is has something to do with how ActionController::TestCase.process fires off requests. I was looking at the source, but its a little over my head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my own experience it appears that RSpec controller tests will *not* attempt to enforce routing behavior as long as the route exists. RSpec does provide route testing, [specifically the `be_routable` matcher](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/routing-specs/be-routable-matcher).

Given the following `route.rb` snippet:

```
post :foo, to: 'foo#create'
```

it appears

```
it "won't work as expected" do
  get :foo
  expect(response).to be_ok #=> pass

  post :foo
  expect(response).to be_ok #=> pass
end
```

will pass. Only when the route is missing entirely from `route.rb` will it fail.

The following will pass and can be used to perform the test we're interested in:

```
it "responds to only the proper HTTP verbs" do
  expect(get: :foo).not_to be_routable #=> pass - Cannot GET ‍♂️
  expect(post: :foo).to be_routable    #=> pass - POST works 
end
```